# PHP session echo not working?

Tags: php, firefox, session

I have a page that generates a $_SESSION['variable'] that is dynamic, so when you refresh the page the session has a different value everytime ( just a value of 0-10 ). But when I refresh the page in firefox, nothing shows up, but in IE it works fine. I also tried in Opera but it doesn't show up there either. Anyone know why it's not echoing, and yes I session_start() at the top of my page so it should work...

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have firebug installed for firefox? If so, do you have [the firecookie addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683)

If so, you should see the presence of PHPSESSID. If you don't see any cookies, then chances are, this is your issue.

Comment: You can also go through View Page Info > Security > View Cookies without needing the Firebug plugin.

Comment: I just installed firecookie, I already had firebug installed. Where do I look to see if its recognized, because right now if I go to my cookies in firefox, i see PHPSESSID twice..

Answer (score 1):

I had a sort-of similar problem just now and the problem was due to the prefix of my URL.!

Let me explain, I defined my session in a page starting WITH "www." but the href to the second page was hastily defined without "www." at the beginning. After checking the COOKIES I realized that there were two distinct IDs for my sessions.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are cookies enabled on Firefox? If they are not you have to enable passing the session ID through the query string. I think that is disabled by default.